# Post request: failed with status code 404

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

This is my first web API. When I run .Net application, I can use swagger to insert text as well with Postman, all requests are successful.

URL:

```
https://localhost:7187/api/Post
```

Response headers:

```
 access-control-allow-origin: *  
 content-length: 0
 date: Sun,27 Mar 2022 22:13:50 GMT
 server: Kestrel
 x-firefox-spdy: h2
```

However, when I try to insert the text from ReactJS I'm getting 400 BadRequest.

Error:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-703c591638cd39b989d55751f755690c-965fb87e2b980e3b-00",
    "errors": {
        "Text": [
            "Post text can not be empty"
        ]
    }
}
```

The API is returning error: "Post text can not be empty", however in Network>REQUEST tab there is a JSON (post:"sometext")

Here is my react attempt to send the data:

```
import React,{ useState} from "react";
import Axios from 'axios';

export function CreatePost(){
    const url = "https://localhost:7187/api/Post";
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        post : ""
    });

    function Submit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        Axios.post(url, {
            post : data.post
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
        })
    }

    function HandleData(e){
        const newData = {...data};
        newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
        setData(newData);
        console.log(newData);
    }
    return(
        <div id="create-post">
            <form onSubmit={(e) => Submit(e)}>
                <input onChange={(e) => HandleData(e)} id="post" value={data.post} type="text" required/>
                <button id="btn-send-post" className="btn">Post</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Update:
I did some simple fetch-Post and it's working. I guess the problem should be in ReactJs section.

Comment: when sending requests using axios you have to wrap your headers as follows. `Axios.post(url,{ headers: {post : data.post }})`

Comment: still it doesn't work

Comment: also make sure to check if data.post is empty before proceeding to make a request.